# View module configuration in App Engine developer's console

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm struggling to understand Google's various administration interfaces regarding the configuration of modules in App Engine.

I have this code in my `app.yaml`

```
application: s~myapp
module: default
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
instance_class: F2
```

I expect to see some part of the App Engine console or the Google Developer's Console that confirms that I have a module called "default" with an `F2` size instance running. However, the App Engine console just says this:

[image: App Engine Console performance settings]

And the Developer's Console just says this:

[image: Developer's Console instances]

...which is a little better because I can see the "default" option in the module dropdown in the top left. But I don't details about what *kind* of instance is running, specifically the `F2` type.

Maybe this information is just not available, but can anyone help clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the admin console, click on *Versions* (under Main). You'll see the performance settings for each version of your app, including the frontend instance class if you've set one for that version explicitly. You can click on the link and see the corresponding config snippets for `app.yaml` and `appengine-web.xml`.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Click Google App Engine at the top left or https://appengine.google.com/ 
Select the App you wish to manage
On the left menu under "Administration' select 'Application'
The 'Application' page is divided into a few sections: Basics at the top and 'Performance'.  In the Performance section you will see the 'Frontend Instance Class:'

If it is not showing make sure you are using the OWNER account. You may also have to be a billing administrator.  I remember I could not see certain areas until I had both assigned.  The frontend instance would effect the billing for the project and may be restricted.

Comment: You can see in my first screenshot that I don't have any info on "Frontend Instance Class" in the Performance section. This is because I've updated my app to use modules (frontends and backends being deprecated). And I'm definitely the owner.